# Was "乎" the man'yōgana spelling of the accusative/object particle "を"?

Tags: etymology, history, particle-を, spelling, manyōgana

[In the English Wiktionary entry for "を"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%92#Particle) there is a quote or example sentence using the character "乎" with no explanation seemingly where the particle "を" would normally occur.

Now I couldn't find anything in either the entry for "乎" or "を" about them being historically connected via [*man'yōgana*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27y%C5%8Dgana), and Google searches failed to turn up anything conclusive either.

In fact I don't know much about *man'yōgana* at all so could it be that any character with the right reading could be used for "を"?

Comment: Another kanji for learners to over-use!  hehehe...

Comment: If you're interested in this stuff I recommend reading "A History of the Japanese Language" by Bjarke Frellesvig.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it was one form. From [here](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%92#.E5.A5.88.E8.89.AF.E6.99.82.E4.BB.A3):

> 奈良時代には、「オ」は [o] 、「ヲ」は [wo]
>   と発音されており明確な区別があった。借字（万葉仮名）では、オには意・憶・於・應（応）・隱（隠）・乙などの字が用いられる一方、「ヲ」には乎・呼・袁・遠・鳥・鳴・怨・越・少・小・尾・麻・男・緒・雄などが用いられていた

**Translation**

In the Nara period, オ was pronounced as "o" and ヲ was pronounced as "wo", and were clearly distinguished. [借字]{しゃくじ}(Manyogana) used 意・憶・於・應（応）・隱（隠）・乙, etc. for オ and 乎・呼・袁・遠・鳥・鳴・怨・越・少・小・尾・麻・男・緒・雄 for ヲ.